# Integer inserted into mysql is not the same when selected from db

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, integer

I have:

```
 $height = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['height'];
```

Which inserts an integer value to an INT database field.

When I select the same value back from the database I get a whole different number...

Is it real escape? Or is it a specific filter that i should use?

Thank you so much

EDIT

First of all, thank all of you who are being a real help!!!

Here is my code:

I have a sql field called height INT(3)

the form input is as such:

the query is:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO patient (height) VALUES ('$height')");
```

the code triggering this query is:

```
if (isset($_POST['dossier'])) {
    $height = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['height']);
}
```

Now, lets say I post 4, then I echo the $height variable I get 5...

First time I get this error...

Thank you so much!!

LAST EDIT

I found the problem!!!

I had a mathematical calculation where I used a wrong operator:

```
if ($row['gender'] === "m") {
                if ($height = 5) { // <------ RIGHT HERE!!!!!
                    $height_measure = 106 + ($height_dec * 6);
}
```

So I changed the operator to === and now everything works fine again!!!!

Thanks for those who tried to help! And those who voted negative, you could have been more of a help and at least direct me to a replicated question or something!!! :) You know, constructive criticism!!!!

Thank you again all!

Comment: What number did you insert, and what is the different number number that you fetch with select? Could it be that you are overflowing the data type?

Comment: hmmmm when I query it back from the database I just use $height = $row['height']; then I echo it within the page as <?php echo $height; ?>

Comment: @BillKarwin i posted some code thanx again guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your height is always integer value I think it's better to use:

```
$height = (int) $_POST['height'];
```

Comment: Hey i wish i could have given you a vote up but i dont have 15 points plus i got -2 for this question!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a mathematical calculation where I used a wrong operator:

```
if ($row['gender'] === "m") {
                if ($height = 5) { // <------ RIGHT HERE!!!!!
                    $height_measure = 106 + ($height_dec * 6);
}
```

So I changed the operator to === and now everything works fine again!!!!